# Android build XDK is not working javascript on device

Tags: android, indexeddb, intel-xdk

I created my application XDK HTML5, and test my app in "EMULATOR" and works perfectly, and when I generate the APK and test on different devices does not work any javascript function. please help

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jqm/jquery.mobile-min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index_main.less.css" class="main-less">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">

    <script src="intelxdk.js"></script>
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script src="xhr.js"></script>
    <script src="xdk/init-dev.js"></script>
    <script type="application/javascript" src="lib/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="application/javascript" src="jqm/jquery.mobile-min.js" data-ver="0"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function(){
                window.indexedDB = window.indexedDB || window.mozIndexedDB || window.webkitIndexedDB || window.msIndexedDB;

                var request, db; 

                if(!window.indexedDB)
                {
                    intel.xdk.notification.alert("No soporta IndexedDB", "Mensaje", "Ok");
                }
                else
                {
                    request = window.indexedDB.open("testDB1", 2);
                    request.onerror = function(event){
                        console.log("Error al abrir la DB", event);
                    }
                    request.onupgradeneeded   = function(event){
                        db = event.target.result;
                        var objectStore = db.createObjectStore("students", { keyPath : "rollNo" });
                    };
                    request.onsuccess  = function(event){
                        intel.xdk.notification.alert("Si soporta IndexedDB", "Mensaje", "Ok");
                        db = event.target.result;
                    }
                }

                $("#addBtn").click(function(){

                    var name = $("#name").val();
                    var rollNo = $("#rollno").val();
                    var precio = $("#precio").val();

                    var transaction = db.transaction(["students"],"readwrite");
                    transaction.oncomplete = function(event) {
                        intel.xdk.notification.alert("Se ingreso a la DB IndexedDB", "Mensaje", "Ok");
                    };

                    transaction.onerror = function(event) {
                        intel.xdk.notification.alert("Error al grabar", "Mensaje", "Ok");
                    };  

                    var objectStore = transaction.objectStore("students");

                    objectStore.add({rollNo: rollNo, name: name, precio: precio});

                    $("#name").val("");
                    $("#rollno").val("");
                    $("#precio").val("");
                });



                $("#btnBuscarE").click(function(){
                    var rollNo = $("#rollnoE").val();
                    var request = db.transaction(["students"],"readwrite").objectStore("students").get(rollNo);
                    request.onsuccess = function(event){
                        $("#rollnoE").val(request.result.rollNo);
                        $("#nameE").val(request.result.name);
                        $("#precioE").val(request.result.precio);
                    };
                });


                $("#btnModificarE").click(function(){
                    var name = $("#nameE").val();
                    var rollNo = $("#rollnoE").val();
                    var precio = $("#precioE").val();

                    var transaction = db.transaction(["students"],"readwrite");
                    var objectStore = transaction.objectStore("students");
                    var request = objectStore.get(rollNo);
                    request.onsuccess = function(event){
                        request.result.rollNo = rollNo;
                        request.result.name = name;
                        request.result.precio = precio;
                        objectStore.put(request.result);
                    };
                    intel.xdk.notification.alert("Se actualizo correctamente el producto", "Mensaje", "Ok");
                    $("#nameE").val("");
                    $("#rollnoE").val("");
                    $("#precioE").val("");
                });



                $("#btnBuscarD").click(function(){
                    var rollNo = $("#rollnoD").val();
                    var request = db.transaction(["students"],"readwrite").objectStore("students").get(rollNo);
                    request.onsuccess = function(event){
                        $("#rollnoD").val(request.result.rollNo);
                        $("#nameD").val(request.result.name);
                        $("#precioD").val(request.result.precio);
                    };
                });


                $("#btnEliminarD").click(function(){
                    var rollNo = $("#rollnoD").val();                    
                    db.transaction(["students"],"readwrite").objectStore("students").delete(rollNo);
                    intel.xdk.notification.alert("Se elimino correctamente el producto", "Mensaje", "Ok");
                    $("#nameD").val("");
                    $("#rollnoD").val("");
                    $("#precioD").val("");
                });

                $("#removeBtn").click(function(){
                    var rollNo = $("#rollno").val();                    
                    db.transaction(["students"],"readwrite").objectStore("students").delete(rollNo);

                });

                $("#getBtn").click(function(){
                    var rollNo = $("#rollno").val();
                    var request = db.transaction(["students"],"readwrite").objectStore("students").get(rollNo);
                    request.onsuccess = function(event){
                        $("#result").html("Name : "+request.result.name);    
                    };
                });

                $("#updateBtn").click(function(){
                    var rollNo = $("#rollno").val();
                    var name = $("#name").val();
                    var transaction = db.transaction(["students"],"readwrite");
                    var objectStore = transaction.objectStore("students");
                    var request = objectStore.get(rollNo);
                    request.onsuccess = function(event){
                        $("#result").html("Updating : "+request.result.name + " to " + name);
                        request.result.name = name;
                        objectStore.put(request.result);
                    };
                });

                $("#ShowAll").click(function(){

                    document.getElementById('resultado').innerHTML = "";
                    var objectStore = db.transaction(['students'], "readonly").objectStore('students');
                    objectStore.openCursor().onsuccess = function(event) {
                    var cursor = event.target.result;
                    if (cursor) {
                        var message = "<ul style='margin: 1em 0 1em -1em;'>";
                        message += "<a href='#' id=''>" +  cursor.value.rollNo + "</a> : " + cursor.value.name + " / " + cursor.value.precio + "<br />";
                        document.getElementById('resultado').innerHTML += message;
                        cursor.continue();

                    }
                     else {
                        message += "</ul>";
                    };

                  };      
                });
            });
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="upage ui-page-theme-b" id="mainpage" data-role="page">
      <div class="upage-outer">
        <div data-role="header" class="container-group inner-element uib_w_1" data-uib="jquery_mobile/header" data-ver="0" data-position="fixed">
          <h1>Inventario</h1>
          <div class="widget-container wrapping-col single-centered"></div>
          <div class="widget-container content-area horiz-area wrapping-col left"></div>
          <div class="widget-container content-area horiz-area wrapping-col right"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="upage-content content-area vertical-col left" id="page_36_19">
          <div class="widget uib_w_25 d-margins AAA" data-uib="media/text" data-ver="0">
            <div class="widget-container left-receptacle"></div>
            <div class="widget-container right-receptacle"></div>
            <div>
              <p>DERECHOS DE AUTOR</p>
              <p>ALLEN BRICEÑO PALACIOS.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div data-role="collapsible" class="no_wrap widget uib_w_2" data-uib="jquery_mobile/collapsible" data-ver="0" data-collapsed="true">
            <h4>Añadir Producto</h4>
            <div class="col uib_col_1 single-col" data-uib="layout/col" data-ver="0">
              <div class="widget-container content-area vertical-col">

                <div class="table-thing with-label widget uib_w_10 d-margins" data-uib="jquery_mobile/input" data-ver="0">
                  <label class="narrow-control label-inline" for="rollno">Codigo</label>
                  <input class="wide-control" placeholder="Ingrese Codigo" type="text" id="rollno">
                </div>
                <div class="table-thing with-label widget uib_w_11 d-margins" data-uib="jquery_mobile/input" data-ver="0">
                  <label class="narrow-control label-inline" for="name">Producto</label>
                  <input class="wide-control" placeholder="Ingrese Producto" type="text" id="name">
                </div>
                <div class="table-thing with-label widget uib_w_12 d-margins" data-uib="jquery_mobile/input" data-ver="0">
                  <label class="narrow-control label-inline" for="precio">Precio</label>
                  <input class="wide-control" placeholder="Ingrese el precio" type="number" id="precio">
                </div><span class="uib_shim"></span>
              </div>
            </div>

            <a class="widget uib_w_9 d-margins" data-uib="jquery_mobile/button" data-ver="0" data-role="button" data-mini="true" id="addBtn">Añadir</a>
          </div>
          <div data-role="collapsible" class="no_wrap widget uib_w_3" data-uib="jquery_mobile/collapsible" data-ver="0" data-collapsed="true">
            <h4>Editar Producto</h4>
            <div class="col uib_col_2 single-col" data-uib="layout/col" data-ver="0">
              <div class="widget-container content-area vertical-col">

                <div class="table-thing with-label widget uib_w_13 d-margins" data-uib="jquery_mobile/input" data-ver="0">
                  <label class="narrow-control label-inline" for="rollnoE">Codigo</label>
                  <input class="wide-control" placeholder="Ingrese codigo" type="text" id="rollnoE">
                </div>
                <div class="table-thing with-label widget uib_w_14 d-margins" data-uib="jquery_mobile/input" data-ver="0">
                  <label class="narrow-control label-inline" for="nameE">Producto</label>
                  <input class="wide-control" placeholder="Producto" type="text" id="nameE">
                </div>
                <div class="table-thing with-label widget uib_w_15 d-margins" data-uib="jquery_mobile/input" data-ver="0">
                  <label class="narrow-control label-inline" for="precioE">Precio</label>
                  <input class="wide-control" placeholder="Precio" type="number" id="precioE">
                </div><a class="widget uib_w_16 d-margins" data-uib="jquery_mobile/button" data-ver="0" data-role="button" data-mini="true" id="btnBuscarE">Buscar Codigo</a><a class="widget uib_w_17 d-margins" data-uib="jquery_mobile/button" data-ver="0" data-role="button"
                data-mini="true" id="btnModificarE">Modificar</a><span class="uib_shim"></span>
              </div>
            </div>

          </div>
          <div data-role="collapsible" class="no_wrap widget uib_w_4" data-uib="jquery_mobile/collapsible" data-ver="0" data-collapsed="true">
            <h4>Eliminar Producto</h4>
            <div class="col uib_col_3 single-col" data-uib="layout/col" data-ver="0">
              <div class="widget-container content-area vertical-col">

                <div class="table-thing with-label widget uib_w_20 d-margins" data-uib="jquery_mobile/input" data-ver="0">
                  <label class="narrow-control label-inline" for="rollnoD">Codigo</label>
                  <input class="wide-control" placeholder="Ingrese codigo" type="text" id="rollnoD">
                </div>
                <div class="table-thing with-label widget uib_w_21 d-margins" data-uib="jquery_mobile/input" data-ver="0">
                  <label class="narrow-control label-inline" for="nameD">Producto</label>
                  <input class="wide-control" placeholder="Producto" type="text" id="nameD">
                </div>
                <div class="table-thing with-label widget uib_w_22 d-margins" data-uib="jquery_mobile/input" data-ver="0">
                  <label class="narrow-control label-inline" for="precioD">Precio</label>
                  <input class="wide-control" placeholder="Precio" type="text" id="precioD">
                </div><a class="widget uib_w_23 d-margins" data-uib="jquery_mobile/button" data-ver="0" data-role="button" data-mini="true" id="btnBuscarD">Buscar Codigo</a><a class="widget uib_w_24 d-margins" data-uib="jquery_mobile/button" data-ver="0" data-role="button"
                data-mini="true" id="btnEliminarD">Eliminar</a>
                <span class="uib_shim"></span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div data-role="collapsible" class="no_wrap widget uib_w_5" data-uib="jquery_mobile/collapsible" data-ver="0" data-collapsed="true">
            <h4>Ver Productos</h4>
            <div class="col uib_col_4 single-col" data-uib="layout/col" data-ver="0">
              <div class="widget-container content-area vertical-col">

                <a class="widget uib_w_18 d-margins" data-uib="jquery_mobile/button" data-ver="0" data-role="button" data-mini="true" id="ShowAll">Actualizar</a>
                <div class="widget uib_w_19 d-margins qs" data-uib="media/text" data-ver="0" id="resultado">
                  <div class="widget-container left-receptacle"></div>
                  <div class="widget-container right-receptacle"></div>

                </div><span class="uib_shim"></span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

I requerid use IndexedDB, for local database use in app; i test build in cross and android version and not working.

Answer (score 0):

The emulator is only a rough approximation to a real device.  I would recommend trying the "Debug" tab, which will allow you to remotely debug a usb connected device.  This should be more like running a built app on the device, especially if it already works in the emulator, which indicates that you're not relying on any plugins that aren't supported in that configuration.  If nothing else, this should at least tell you where it's failing which would enable you to ask a more detailed question.

You should also check to make sure that you're including all of the plugins you need on the project page.  The emulator usually does this, but might not be perfect in that aspect of emulation.